# react router - params in routes with fixed values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Is there a way to define a dynamic route with fixed set of values? And if it doesn't fit any of the fixed values it would fallback to the next route. My current is like this -

```
const routes = {
  path: '',
  component: AppComponent,
  childRoutes: [
    { path: '/search/top', name: 'top', component: FixedSearchComponent},
    { path: '/search/new', name: 'new', component: FixedSearchComponent},
    { path: '/search', name: 'search', component: SearchComponent},
    { path: '/search/:query', name: 'search', component: SearchComponent},
  ]
}
```

But I'd like to define a parameter for it like `:fixedSearch` maybe and have it predefined to only be this values. Maybe something like this? And if it doesn't fit any of `top` or `new` (or other possible set), it would fallback to `search`.

```
const routes = {
  path: '',
  component: AppComponent,
  childRoutes: [
    { path: '/search/:fixedSearch', name: 'fixedSearch', fixedSearch: ['top', 'new'], component: FixedSearchComponent},
    { path: '/search', name: 'search', component: SearchComponent},
    { path: '/search/:query', name: 'search', component: SearchComponent},
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could attach an `onEnter` function a new route, like `/fixed/:fixedSearch` that replaces `/search/new` and `/search/top`. Inside the `onEnter` function you would compare `:fixedSearch` to your predefined values (`['top', 'new']`) and if they don't match you can fallback to your `/search` route. This is common for checking if a user is authenticated before allowing access to a route.

Here's the documentation for `onEnter`:

> `onEnter(nextState, replace, callback?)`
>
> Called when a route is about to be entered. It provides the next
>   router state and a function to redirect to another path. this will be
>   the route instance that triggered the hook.
>
> If callback is listed as a 3rd argument, this hook will run
>   asynchronously, and the transition will block until callback is
>   called.

A rough example (in JSX) might look like:

```
<Route path='/fixed/:fixedSearch' component={FixedSearchComponent} onEnter={checkFixedSearch} />

function checkFixedSearch(nextState, replace) {

    if (*Compare :fixedSearch with predefined values*) {
        replace('/search') // move to search route if fixed values don't match
    }
}
```

Comment: I have also thought about this but wouldn't it still enter the first `search` route it hits meaning it would still go to `/search/:fixedSearch`?

Comment: You're right. What about having another route (like `/search/fixed`) that replaces 'top' and 'new' and has the `onEnter` function like I described. If the params match any of your preset values then it will enter the route otherwise you send the user back to `/search`.

Comment: That's actually my temp fix right now where I added `/page/:fixedSearch` right now.